# Puppet notify service error

Tags: puppet

I try to write a puppet configuration in order to install lamp env.

But i have an issue with notify option.

I have an apache conf:

```
class apache inherits apache::params {
    package { 'apache':
        name => "${apache::params::package}",
        ensure => present
    }

    service { 'apache':
        ensure    => running,
        name      => $apache::params::service,
        enable    => true,
        subscribe => Package['apache'],
    }
}
```

and and php module conf:

```
define php::module(
    $notify         = $php::params::notify,
    $package_prefix = $php::params::module_package_prefix
) {
    package { "php-module-${name}":
        ensure  => present,
        name    => "${package_prefix}${name}",
        notify  => Service['apache'],
        require => [Class['apache'], Package['php', 'php-dev']]
    }
}
```

but when I launch puppet I have this error:

```
Error: Parameter notify failed on Php::Module[mcrypt]: No title provided and "apache" is not a valid resource reference
```

I don't understand why it said that apache service is not a valid resources ?

Comment: In some cases it could be just `Service["apache2"]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there might be 2 issues here:

1) Puppet doesn't like this line in php::module:

```
    $notify         = $php::params::notify,
```

Can you try to remove that or check what is in $php::params::notify? (I don't see you using it)

2) Did you have something like

```
include apache
```

in your site.pp? The class still needs to be declared before you can reference the contained resources.

Comment: Yeah puppet failed because i'm using $notify as var name. On my example I did not use $notify but in reality I use: Service["${notify}"];
But if i change $notify by $nofity_service it's works. $notify might be a reserved variable name.